# HTML Canvas Not Drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a script that will draw squares onto a canvas, but when I run my code the canvas is just white, did I miss something?. Here is my code.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
canvas.id = "canvas"
container.append(canvas);
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(242, 144, 7, 1)"
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(242, 144, 7, 1)"
ctx.rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
```

There were no errors in the console,

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a few lines of code

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
canvas.id = "canvas"
container.append(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(242, 144, 7, 1)"
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(242, 144, 7, 1)"
ctx.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `rgba` is you are passing 4 values

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(242, 144, 7, 1)"
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(242, 144, 7, 1)"
ctx.rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but that didn't fix it